# Masonry giving container 0 height

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, jquery-masonry

I'm working on some stuff that involves a responsive masonry layout. I have a container that has a max-width of `960px` but scales down with the browser. My grid items have a percentage-based width (100%, 66.666666etc%, 33.33333etc%). For some reason, when I pass a function to the `columnWidth` option, it always gives the container a height of 0. This is how I'm instantiating Masonry.

```
$(window).load(function() {
  var $container;
  $container = $("#grid_container");
  $container.masonry({
    columnWidth: function(containerWidth) {
      return containerWidth / 3;
    },
    itemSelector: ".grid_item",
    isFitWidth: true,
    isResizable: true,
    gutter: 10
  });
});
```

Any idea why it'd be doing this? Since I'm using `$(window).load` it should be able to calculate the height fine. Am I missing something really obvious here? Is it simply not possible to use percentage column widths with Masonry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Masonry, a function type isn't a permitted value for the [`columnWidth` property](http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#columnwidth).

Try instead to:

1. Pass a CSS selector (e.g., `.grid_box`) as the `columnWidth` property.
2. In CSS, add the selector to the appropriate percentage width of its parent container (e..g, `.grid_box{ width: 20%; }`).
3. To your HTML, add an empty `<div class="grid_box"></div>` to the container.

Comment: You're pointing to the v2 documentation. v3 is the latest. Which version are you using?

Comment: Oh, weird. I'm using v3...I didn't realize he removed that ability. Very weird. In the end I ended up just going with Salvattore over Masonry. Thanks for pointing that out though, good to know in the future.