# Masonry an Woocommerce Cart widget conflict?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, woocommerce, masonry

I've posted some questions about Masonry on de Woocommerce shop page. Bottom line I had an image overlap issue. I found a solution at [masonry desandro](http://masonry.desandro.com/). I needed the imagesLoaded script. OK that works. The second problem I encountered was that the shopping cart was not visible on my pages, just the widget title. You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580106/woocommerce-cart-widget-displays-no-content) the post about that topic.

I found with help that the issue was in the Masonry script as I had implement it. The way I did it came from a course on lynda.com.

Here is the code:

```
function twentytwelve_child_masonry() {
if (!is_admin()) {
    wp_enqueue_script('masonry');

    add_action('wp_footer', 'twentytwelve_child_add_masonry');      
    function twentytwelve_child_add_masonry() { ?>
        <script>
                    (function( $ ) {
                        "use strict";
                        $(function() {
                        //set the container that Masonry will be inside of in a var
                        var container = document.querySelector('.products');
                        //create empty var msnry
                        var msnry;
                        // initialize Masonry after all images have loaded
  //->                      imagesLoaded( container, function() {
                            msnry = new Masonry( container, {
                                itemSelector: '.product',
                                isAnimated: true
                            });
                        });
  //->                  });
                        }(jQuery));
        </script>
    <?php 
    }
  }
}
add_action('init', 'twentytwelve_child_masonry');
```

The two lines marked with //-> are responsiple for running or not running the imagesLoaded script.

However when this imagesLoaded script runs the masonry works perfect, the woocommorce cart widget is not.
When the imagesLoaded script is commented out, de masonry is a mess (overlapping images) but the woocommerce cart widget works lik a charm.

Anyone an idea? I'm e bit of a newbie so any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

See updated code below.

```
function script_imagesLoaded (){
wp_register_script ('images_loaded' , get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/imagesloaded.js' , Array() , '3.1.8' ,true);
wp_enqueue_script ('images_loaded');
}
add_action('init' , 'script_imagesLoaded');

function twentytwelve_child_masonry() {
if (!is_admin()) {
    wp_enqueue_script('masonry');

    add_action('wp_footer', 'twentytwelve_child_add_masonry');      
    function twentytwelve_child_add_masonry() { ?>
        <script>                                             
                    (function( $ ) {
                        "use strict";
                        $(function() { 
                         imagesLoaded( 'body', function() {
                            alert ('All images have loaded!');
                        });    
                        //set the container that Masonry will be inside of in a var
                        var container = document.querySelector('.products');
                        //create empty var msnry
                        var msnry;
                        // initialize Masonry after all images have loaded
                        imagesLoaded( container, function() {
                            msnry = new Masonry( container, {
                                itemSelector: '.product',
                                isAnimated: true
                            });

                            });
                        });
                        }(jQuery));
        </script>
    <?php 
    }
}
}
add_action('init', 'twentytwelve_child_masonry');
```

**EDIT3**
[image]

Comment: We meet again: it sounds like your issue *isn't* to with Masonry. Without seeing a complete page I can only make an educated guess: the imagesLoaded script is causing the errors. The reason Masonry looks funny is that the imagesLoaded script is responsible for making sure the images are present *before* the Masonry script kicks in. Assuming that you've definitely got the imagesLoaded script running you should try commenting out the 4x lines that create the Masonry object, put the imagesLoaded lines back in and add a `window.console.log('container');` inside the callback function.

Comment: We're trying to find out *if* imagesLoaded is firing correctly and whether the `container` variable actually contains anything. Post any error messages that it shows and maybe we can track down the issue

Comment: In the console I See the script masonry.min.js loaded. That script is the standard Wordpress masonry. Looking in the console I don't see that imagesLoaded.js is called and running. In the masonry script imagesLoaded is found twice. I don't know if that's sufficient (I don't have much knowledge of javascript). When I remove the masonry lines form code above and just add the imagesLoaded line together with the console line you provided, no failures are detected nor can I see that imagesLoaded is fired.

Comment: BTW When I put in a Masonry script from masonry.desandro.com (masonry.pkgd.min.js) imagesLoaded is defenatly not fired. I got an error: Reference Error: Can't find variable imagesLoaded. This way masonry don't work. I hope this clear it a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working at last. It was needed to download a total of 4 js scripts from GitHub.

```
masonry.pkgd.min.js
inagesloaded.js
eventie.js
eventemitter.js
```

Next I created the following function:

```
 function twentytwelve_child_masonry() {
 if (!is_admin()) {

            wp_register_script ('eventemitter_loaded' , get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/eventEmitter.js' , Array() , '4.2.11' ,true);
            wp_enqueue_script ('eventemitter_loaded');

            wp_register_script ('eventie_loaded' , get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/eventie.js' , Array() , '1.0.5' ,true);
            wp_enqueue_script ('eventie_loaded');

            wp_register_script ('images_loaded' , get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/imagesloaded.js' , Array() , '3.1.8' ,true);
            wp_enqueue_script ('images_loaded');

            wp_register_script('twentytwelve_child_masonry', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js' , array(),'3.2.1', true);
            wp_enqueue_script('twentytwelve_child_masonry');

           add_action('wp_footer', 'twentytwelve_child_add_masonry');       
           function twentytwelve_child_add_masonry() { ?>
              <script>
                    (function( $ ) {
                        "use strict";
                        $(function() {
                        //set the container that Masonry will be inside of in a var
                        var container = document.querySelector('#masonry_wrapper');
                        //create empty var msnry
                        var msnry;
                        // initialize Masonry after all images have loaded
                        imagesLoaded( container, function() {
                            msnry = new Masonry( container, {
                                itemSelector: '.product',
                                isAnimated: true
                            });
                            });
                        });
                        }(jQuery));
        </script>
    <?php 
    }
 }
 }
```

In the product-archive.php file I wrapped the loop in a separate div. (#masonry_wrapper).
Next and last I called the function above from within product-archive.php.
Special thanks to Dre who helped me a lot. See the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments it sounds like `imagesLoaded.js` is not being loaded, which is why you're having issues:

1. Go to the [Images Loaded  page on Github](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) and download the latest version.
2. Put downloaded files in your theme folder with your other JS files.
3. Enqueue the script using [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) - here's a [pretty good guide](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-add-javascripts-and-styles-in-wordpress/)  on how to do this if you've never done it before. Loading it in the footer should be fine.

Once you've done all that you can confirm it's loaded and running by popping the following JS on the page/in your script files:

```
imagesLoaded( 'body', function() {
    alert ('All images have loaded!');
});
```

That should trigger an alert when all the images on the page have loaded.

Incidentally you mentioned that you got this code from a course at Lynda.com - do you have a link to this? I'm surprised they didn't point out that you need to make sure that you the ImagesLoaded scripts included.

Comment: I downloaded the file from github, put the imagesLoaded.js v 3.1.8 in themes js folder, enqueued it (see the code edit in my question above) and added the function you pointed out. I see in the markup that imagesloaded.js is before masonry-min.js. When loading the page the alert box shows. I see the images lined up beneath eachother and when hitting OK masonry kicks in and show me the intended layout. However the Woocommerce Cart Widget is not working. Switching off imagesLoaded messes up my layout but the cartwidget is updating. Also see the code above. What am I doing wrong....????

Comment: Get these messages in the console: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new EventEmitter()') (13:21:20:379 | error, javascript)
    at factory (http://localhost/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/js/imagesloaded.js?ver=3.1.8:125:43)
    at (anonymous function) (http://localhost/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/js/imagesloaded.js?ver=3.1.8:32:33)

Comment: No, I'm sorry I develop locally. I can provide some screenshots but I don't know if that's helpfull.

Comment: OK, I'll need to reproduce the same problem locally. Can you confirm then that: 1. The only plugin active is WooCommerce and you still get this problem 2. The only additional JS is imagesLoaded and Masonry. 3. You're using the default WC cart widget.

If I can make the error happen on my local set up I might be able to track down the issue. I can't guarantee it though.

Comment: Thank you again for helpign me out. I have some other plug-ins running. I wil switch them off,try it, and get back to you.

Comment: With all plug-ins deactivate (except woocommerce) the problem persists.

Comment: I think I made some progress. In the script is the line `var container = document.querySelector('.products');` When I change `.products` into `#content` the masonry works and the products are shown in the cart widget. However it looks likes the height of the page is now be determent by the height of the sidebar contents. The woocommerce pagination is moved to the top of the page and the height of all pages is to less to show all the content. I've tried to wrap it in its own div to no avail. Any suggestions? See EDIT 3 above.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to get a local copy up yet, but it sounds like you're getting somewhere. Sounds like you didn't have `.products` on the page but you do have `#content`. Without seeing all your markup this should work providing you always have an element with an id of content on every page. Regarding the new layout issue; try following the [steps 2 and 3 of the answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21394607/masonry-giving-container-0-height) as it's essentially the same problem you are facing.

Comment: Sure, there was a `.products` tag. Don't know why it was working so badly. I wrapped the `ul class="products"`in a new div `#masonry_wrapper`, set this new div as container in the script and de li items `.product` as the item selector. Masonry works, cart widget don't. Back to square one. I thought perhaps when I wrap the whole function in a conditional in my functions.php it maybe will work. Something like `if not an admin page and it is page('pagename')` run it. However this did not work. I'm looking for a working conditional now...... Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What I absolutly don't understand is why the function interfere with pages who don't have the `#masonry_wrapper` div in it. The scrips are fired anyway and imagesLoaded.js produces an error: `[Error] TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'obj.length')
 makeArray (imagesloaded.js, line 69)
 ImagesLoaded (imagesloaded.js, line 98)
 ImagesLoaded (imagesloaded.js, line 91)
 (anonieme functie) (localhost, line 284)
 j (jquery.js, line 2)
 fireWith (jquery.js, line 2)
 ready (jquery.js, line 2)
 J (jquery.js, line 2)` I think that this is the cause of all my trouble....